# To find $\beta_1, \beta_2$ in order to satisfy $2^2 p_1^{a_1+1-\beta_1}p_2^{a_2+1-\beta_2}p_3^{a_3}p_4^{a_4}=(p_1-1)(p_2-1)$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

Question: We need to find positive integers $\beta_1, \beta_1$ such that 
\begin{align}
&2^2 p_1^{a_1+1-\beta_1}p_2^{a_2+1-\beta_2}p_3^{a_3}p_4^{a_4}=(p_1-1)(p_2-1).........(1)
\end{align}
holds where $p_1<p_2<p_3<p_4$ are given odd primes and $a_1, a_2,a_3,a_4$ are positive integers.

I have tried to solve in the following manner.

First we note that $1\leqslant \beta_1\leqslant a_1+1, 1\leqslant \beta_2\leqslant a_2+1.$

Next , since $p_1, p_2$ are odd primes, so we can assume that 
\begin{align}
&p_1-1=2^{e_1}p_2^{\gamma_{21}}p_3^{\gamma_{31}}p_4^{\gamma_{41}}.......(2)\\
&p_2-1=2^{e_2}p_1^{\gamma_{12}}p_3^{\gamma_{32}}p_4^{\gamma_{42}}.......(3)
\end{align}
where $e_1, e_2\in \mathbb{N}$ and $\gamma_{i1}, \gamma_{i2}\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.

Hence (1) gives: $e_1+e_2=2$ i.e. $e_1=e_2=1$.

$(i)~\gamma_{12}=a_1+1-\beta_1$

$(ii)~\gamma_{21}=a_2+1-\beta_2$

$(iii)~\gamma_{31}+\gamma_{32}=a_3$

$(iv)~\gamma_{41}+\gamma_{42}=a_4$

Now if $\gamma_{31}>0$ then $p_1=2p_2^{\gamma_{21}}p_3^{\gamma_{31}}p_4^{\gamma_{41}}>p_3$ which is contradiction. Thus $\gamma_{31}=0$. Hence $\gamma_{32}=a_3\geqslant 1$ and thus 
$p_2=2p_1^{\gamma_{12}}p_3^{\gamma_{32}}p_4^{\gamma_{42}}>p_3$, contradiction again.

Conclusion: No such positive integers $\beta_1, \beta_2$ exists.

My sincere request to you all, please check it and kindly tell me if I have made any mistake or is there anything extra I need to cover up but forgot.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> please check it and kindly tell me if I have made any mistake or is there anything extra I need to cover up but forgot

You are correct except one typo

> Thus $\gamma_{21}=0$

This should be $\gamma_{31}=0$.

---

You can write your idea simply as the following :

$$2^2 p_1^{a_1+1-\beta_1}p_2^{a_2+1-\beta_2}p_3^{a_3}p_4^{a_4}=(p_1-1)(p_2-1)$$

Since $p_1-1\lt p_1\lt p_3$ and $p_2-1\lt p_2\lt p_3$, the RHS is not divisible by $p_3$ while the LHS is divisible by $p_3$.

Comment: truely. Thank you so much. I am going through your suggestive answer. If I have any doubt I will post :-) thank u again

Comment: @Anjan3: You are welcome. (The answer uses that $p_3$ divides either $p_1-1$ or $p_2-1$ and that if $a\gt 0$ divides $b\gt 0$, then $b\ge a$ holds.)